Using py4j register for DJI android sdk
Ok, so this is rather complicated. I am trying to integrate YOLOv8(and potentially more machine learning stuff) on my DJI drone. my drone only supports DJI android msdk and yet I am more familiar and comfortable using Python. Thus I've decided to use py4j to create a gateway server to launch a JVM, in that case, I can run my YOLO code on the Python side and drone command on the Java side. However, DJI msdk is built for the Android development environment and it has an SDK key that needs to be filled in the AndroidManifest file before using the API. However, since I am not in an Android environment, I used another function called setAppKey() and called the function from my python side, this is what I got:
raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling t.sdkSetUp.
: java.lang.VerifyError: Constructor must call super() or this() before return
Exception Details:
  Location:
    dji/sdk/sdkmanager/DJISDKManager.<init>()V @0: return
  Reason:
    Error exists in the bytecode
  Bytecode:
    0000000: b12a 5959 5c5c 5c5c 5c5c 5c5c 5c5c b700
    0000010: ff03 b501 0101 b501 03bb 0105 5903 b701
    0000020: 08b5 010a b801 0ebe 0464 b501 1003 b501
    0000030: 12bb 0056 59b8 0117 bb00 2859 2ab7 011a
    0000040: b701 1db5 011f 01b5 0121 bb01 2359 b701
    0000050: 24b5 0126 01b5 0128 01b5 012a 01b5 012c
    0000060: 01b5 012e 01b5 0130 01b5 0132 01b5 0134
    0000070: 01b5 0136 bb00 2259 2ab7 0137 b501 39bb
    0000080: 0020 592a b701 3ab5 013c bb01 3e59 03b7
    0000090: 0141 b501 43bb 0016 592a b701 44b5 0146
    00000a0: bb00 1459 2ab7 0147 b501 49bb 0012 592a
    00000b0: b701 4ab5 014c b801 51b8 0154 57a7 0034
    00000c0: 4bb2 0156 592a b801 5c03 bd00 04b8 0162
    00000d0: bb01 6459 b701 6513 0167 b800 ebb6 016b
    00000e0: 2ab6 016f b601 6bb6 0172 03bd 0004 b801
    00000f0: 62b1                                   
  Exception Handler Table:
    bci [182, 188] => handler: 192
  Stackmap Table:
    full_frame(@192,{},{Object[#254]})
    same_frame(@241)

    at org.example.Main.sdkSetUp(Main.java:19)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)


Python side code
from py4j.java_gateway import JavaGateway

gateway = JavaGateway()

addition_app = gateway.entry_point

addition_app.sdkSetUp()

print("DJI sdk set up success!")

Java side code
package org.example;

import py4j.GatewayServer;

import dji.sdk.sdkmanager.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main app = new Main();
        GatewayServer server = new GatewayServer(app);
        server.start();
        System.out.println("Gateway Server Started");
    }

    public void sdkSetUp(){
        DJISDKManager.setAppKey("some-hashed-sdk-key-generated-from-website");
    }
}

The gatewayServer can start just fine but when I call the sdkSetup function thats when everything starts to falling apart... I actually have quite a few questions, If you could answer any one of them I would be much appreciated. Thank you!

For DJI Android SDK, can I use it in a regular Java enviroment instead of android?
Does setAppKey() does the same thing as go to the AndroidManifest file to modify the sdk key?
For the purpose of my project, is there are a easier way to achieve the same goal? (bypass the android enviroment and run YOLO on DJI).

I tried to create a Mockup android context class and a resource class as these are the function registerApp() input from DJI msdk, but that will need to importing Android core and even though I did so I can't find the corresponding Android package...enter image description here

The way you're going about this is... interesting to say the least. The DJI Android SDK needs to be used in an Android app environment. Even if you could use it outside of an Android app, it relies on the JNI to link C libraries that at the very least would require an ARM device running a Linux-based OS.
I would suggest trying one of two things:

Find a CV library that works in Java. OpenCV and TFLite can both be imported and used in an Android project like any other Java library

Build an API. Write your Python code in Python, and then use Flask to expose an API that your Android app can call and pass images to


Something I personally did when doing a similar project was a mix of both - Use TFLite to crop the drone images on the Android device only to objects of interest, and then send them off to an API to be processed in Python for more detailed analysis.
